# Scientific Atlanta 2100 cable modem lights do not come on

Tags: cable-modem

Just got a cable modem, which I am trying to "install".

I connected all the cables and the power, then all the lights came on and stayed on, no blinking. After about 6 hours with no change, I tried disconnecting and then reconnecting the power.

Now the PC light blinks once when I plug in the power, after that nothing lights up, not even the power.

Is this just a dud modem? Anyone have any idea what I could do to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was a defect modem. Got new modem worked straigh away.